# Get data from MYSQL stored procedure with Express, node and angular JS

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, stored-procedures, mean-stack

I have issue when getting data from getting MYSQL stored procedure with Express 4, node and angular JS.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at r.$scope.getInfo (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/controller.js:96:47)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:213:110), <anonymous>:4:212)
    at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:254:74)
    at r.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:133:313)
    at r.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:134:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:254:126)
    at If (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:35:367)
    at HTMLButtonElement.Hf.d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:35:314)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12520
```

Models/connection.js

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
//console.log("yess");
var MySQLConfig = require('../config/config').MySQLConfig;

exports.createConnection = function () {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: MySQLConfig.host,
        port: MySQLConfig.port,
        user: MySQLConfig.user,
        password: MySQLConfig.password,
        database: MySQLConfig.database
    });
    //console.log("yess");
    console.log(connection);
    return connection;
};
```

public/js/controller.js

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);

    // configure our routes
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

        $stateProvider 


            .state('profile', {
                url: '/profile',
                redirectTo:  'profile.business-information',
                templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
                  controller:  'ProfileController'
            })

            .state('profile.business-information', {
                  url: "/business-information",
                  templateUrl: "templates/profileViews/businessInformation.html" ,
                  controller:  'BusinessInfoController'
            });



    }]); 


app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 
 function($rootScope, $state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params);
      }
    }
  );
}]);

app.controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.dropLink = '1';
  $scope.dropContentLink = '1';

}]);

app.factory('infoService', ['$resource', function($resource){
  //return null;
  return $resource('/api/business-information/:id');
}]);


app.controller('BusinessInfoController', ['$scope', function($scope, infoService) { 

  $scope.isActive = 1;
  $scope.is_active_label = 'Active';



  $scope.getInfo = function() {
      console.log("hiiii");
      console.log($scope.businessInformation.industryID);
      console.log(infoService);
      $scope.businessInformation = infoService.query('BB333');
  };


}]);
```

routes/api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var DBManager = require('../models/connection');

router.route('/business-information/:id')

    .get(function(req, res){

        var conn = DBManager.createConnection();
        conn.connect(function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
                return;
            }
            console.log('connected as id ' + conn.threadId);
        });

        conn.query('Industrys_info_Get(?)', [req.params.id],function(err,info){
          if(err) res.send(err);

          res.json(info);
          console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
          console.log(info[0]);
        });
    }) ;

module.exports = router;
```

html file:

```
<div class='col-lg-6 right_content_BI'>
         <button ng-click='getInfo()' class='edit_btn reset_btn pull-right'></button>
         <input class='industryID pull-right' ng-model="businessInformation.industryID" type='text' id='industryName' placeholder='BEE2034'/>
      </div>
```

Can you help me please to find the issue?

Thank you

Comment: conn is undefined, try to set outside the route the declare: var conn = DBManager.createConnection();

Comment: thank you for your response, it's show the same issue

Comment: You have missing dependency after `app.controller('BusinessInfoController', ['$scope',` <- add `'infoService'`

Comment: Thanks Molda, but now I have this issue:GET http://localhost:3000/api/business-information 404 (Not Found)